# How to make this type of prisma model?

Tags: database, next.js, database-design, prisma

I want to create model schema like below using prism. How can I do it? I don't really understand how I would do or create the model schema. Please help me to like this schema.

[image]

I don't understand how I can do that so I haven't tried.